# why debian run cron scheduled task immediately after wake up from sleep?

Tags: debian, cron

I have a cron job that locks the computer using i3lock at a certain time (12:15), but sometimes I put the computer to sleep before 12:15. If I then I wake up the computer after 12:15 (usually around 13:30), the computer gets locked immediately after wake-up. Why is that?

My OS is Debian buster x86-64.

Comment: You have not added (yet) into this question details about how you "lock your computer". (for example the exact crontab command). If you do it, it will be reasonably easy for people to reproduce this issue, and probably identify the reason of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know about anacron, but as I check its configuration, anacron is clearly not responsible for the immediately sleep after wake up. I read the manual about cron, and found out

> Special  considerations  exist  when  the  clock is changed by less
> than 3 hours, for example at the beginning and end of daylight savings
> time.  If the time has moved forwards, those jobs which would have run
> in the time that was skipped will be run  soon  after the  change.
> Conversely, if the time has moved backwards by less than 3 hours,
> those jobs that fall into the repeated time will not be re-run.
>
> Only jobs that run at a particular time (not specified as @hourly, nor
> with '*' in the hour or minute specifier) are affected.  Jobs which
> are specified with wildcards are run based on the new time
> immediately.
>
> Clock changes of more than 3 hours are considered to be corrections to
> the clock, and the new time is used immediately.

and I checked the log of cron `sudo journalctl -xu cron`, it did have entry tell me that cron is running the missed cron job after waking up

Comment: If this is a clarification to your question rather than an answer, then please delete this answer and move the text into the question instead.

Comment: It seems that what this answer is missing is the connection between the quoted sections of text and the observed behavior.  The text talks about daylight saving and resetting the clock and says nothing about sleep.  Also, the last part about reading the cron log just states that "yes, the job was run". Meanwhile, the question is "_why_ was the job run?"  This is why I first assumed that this was a clarification of the question rather than an answer.

Comment: Indeed, putting the laptop to sleep and waking it up -- assuming some form of time synchronization -- would be seen as a jump in time. If the "lock" cron job is indeed for 12:15, then the quoted section implies that the job would be skipped. It seems to me that you haven't yet found the explanation for the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is is the laptop is sleeping and the jobs run that are backed up. You should just lock it and not put it in sleep mode or follow this guide.

https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/wake-cron.html